# Regular expressions not splitten Python

Tags: python, regex

Using python I'm trying to divide a text file in blocks using regular expression. The text file looks like this:

```
Block1
  u 0.00 2.00
  0.11 2.11
Block2
  v 0.00 2.01
  0.01 2.11
Block3
  a 1.01 2.02
  0.01 2.11
```

my regular expression

```
re.split("(\bBlock1\b\n\s\s[u].*\n.*)", open('Blockfile.txt', "r").read())
```

However when I run the code it doesn't split.
see my regex code here: https://regex101.com/r/jW7oP4/2

Thanks!!

Comment: Show us the whole program, including output, and explain how that output differs from what you wanted.  Posting one line of code and telling us "it didn't work" is not nearly enough detail for us to help you.

Comment: Can this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jW7oP4/3) help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need regular expressions and can approach it line by line checking if a line starts with `Block` collecting the results into a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Block"):
            key = line.strip()
        else:
            data[key].append(line.strip())

print(dict(data))
```

Prints:

```
{
  'Block3': ['a 1.01 2.02', '0.01 2.11'], 
  'Block2': ['v 0.00 2.01', '0.01 2.11'], 
  'Block1': ['u 0.00 2.00', '0.11 2.11']
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I was on this the whole day so I simply forgot that there are also more simpler ways to this trick.

Answer (score 0):

Always, *ALWAYS* use raw strings when working with regular expressions in Python. `\b` means backslash inside a string, it gets evaluated and your regex gets damaged. Just add an 'r' in front of string.
This will do the trick:

```
re.split(r"(\bBlock1\b\n\s\s[u].*\n.*)", open('Blockfile.txt', "r").read())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I indeed forgot to add the "r" but it still seems not good. but I think the way @alecxe explained it should work as well!

Answer (score 0):

`Split` only splits on the argument with its speech marks, for example:

Splitting *"this string"* with `.split(" ")` results in:

```
["this","string"]
```

But splitting it with `.split("s ")` results in:

```
["thi", "string"]
```

Rather than:

```
["thi", "tring"]
```

Which is your problem. Your code will only split when it gets `(\bBlock1\b\n\s\s[u].*\n.*)` all in one go!

I suggest using multiple split functions or a different function like `translate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
If you take a look to my regex example you can see that it was all in one go! or do you mean something else?